Blazor Component only displays the RenderFragment Parameter
I have created a simple Blazor Component for my project that has a button on top and and a conditional rendering where I pass a RenderFragment type. Here the component.
<div class="">
    <button class="btn btn-link w-100" @onclick="Toggle">
        <b>GroupTitle</b>
    </button>
    @if (!ShowContent)
    {
        <div>
            @CollapsibleContent
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] 
    public string? GroupTitle { get; set; }
    [Parameter] 
    public RenderFragment CollapsibleContent { get; set; }

    public bool ShowContent { get; set; } = false;

    public void Toggle() {
        ShowContent = !ShowContent;
    }
}

My problem is that ONLY the @CollapsibleContentdisplays and not the button! Even when I inspect the web page things look off.
Inspected Content on Web Page
I have tried to change some elements and add some simple text to see if it shows up but it does not work.
Here is how I implement the component:
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-width: 100;">
        @foreach(var pair in Menu)
        {

            <CollapsibleMenu GroupTitle="@pair.Key">
                <CollapsibleContent>
                    <ul class="list-group">

                        @foreach(DataRow row in pair.Value)
                        {
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                @(row["SortOrder"])
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </CollapsibleContent>
            </CollapsibleMenu> 
        }
    </div>
</div>


Can you update your question to include the code where you actually use this component and pass in the parameters? Btw, and this may just be a typo, but <b>GroupTitle</b> should be <b>@GroupTitle</b>

There is no <div class=""> in the screenshot. Impossible to link up. Better post a [mre]

What is the component name? If it is collapsiblemenu, change it to CollapsibleMenu. It looks like it is not being recognised as a component because it is all lowercase.

Yes, it is CollapsibleMenu with the right capitalization. I'll add the implementation.

There are inconsistencies in your code.
Case matters in components., and components must start with a capital letter so collapsiblemenu is not your component name, nor is collapsiblecontent the name of the render fragment.
It should look more like this:
<CollapsibleMenu ....>
  <CollapsibleContent>
     ....
  </CollapsibleContent>
</CollapsibleMenu>

What you're currently seeing is just rendering of unknown tags.
